# initializing Array with Objects via map function

Tags: javascript

I don't know why isnt this snippet working:

```
Array(50).map(e => { e = {id: Math.random() , content: 'some_content'}; return e });
```

Comment: Use `Array.from({length: 50})` as `Array.from({length: 50}).map(e => ({id: Math.random() , content: 'some_content'}));`.

Comment: nice make it an answer so i can accept it

Comment: [What is "undefined x 1" in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10683773)

Comment: Uninitialized array entries are skipped over by `map`, `foreach` etc. You can use spread syntax to create an iterable of n elements `[...Array(50)].map()`

Answer (score 1):

It of course does what you told it to do, just not what you want it to do.

The problem is that the `map` function ["is invoked *only* for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including undefined."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  Calling `Array(50)` creates 50 empty slots, but does not assign to them, so the map does nothing.

As [someone else suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110332/238884), you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to quickly create an array of 50 elements, assigned to `undefined`.

Comment: @MattEllen -- there is a difference between an unassigned element and an element assigned to `undefined`.  So far as I know, the only way to test that difference directly is with `hasOwnProperty()`, but this problem demonstrates the issue indirectly.

Comment: It's also an issue between Firebug and Firefox's consoles. Firefox says "`[ <10 empty slots>, 40 more... ]`" whereas Firebug shows me an array of 50 `undefine`ds. I guess it's time to ditch Firebug :D

Comment: It's also akin to a sparse array, e.g. `let x = [1,2]; x[7] = 3;`. Entires 2...6 will be unassigned and skipped by `map`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = Array.apply(null, { length: 50 }).map(e => { e = {id: Math.random() , content: 'some_content'}; return e });
console.log(result);
```

or

```js
  var result = [...Array(50)].map(e => { e = {id: Math.random() , content: 'some_content'}; return e });
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Array.apply(null, { length: 50 })` wont work for  lengths > 500000 (in firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.apply` and wrap the mapped return value in parenthesis, to return an object.

```js
var array = Array.apply(null, { length: 50 }).map(_ => ({id: Math.random() , content: 'some_content'}));
console.log(array)
```

Comment: we are talking about 50 elements here. i see no performance problem ...

Comment: yes, I know ... depends if someone wants 50, or 5000000 random numbers :p (oh, and it's not SLOW, that was my bad :p )